# JOIN on string fields returns no match

Tags: mysql

I have a query with two inner joins. Everything works fine and I get the desired data from the database, until I try to add a `left join` where I compare two strings. So, everything looks like this:

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM table_1
      INNER JOIN on table_2 WHERE table_1.id=table_2.id
      INNER JOIN on table_3 WHERE table_1.integer_value=table_3.int_value
      LEFT JOIN table_4 ON table_3 WHERE table_3.string_value=table_4.string_value';
```

This returns nothing. If I remove the `LEFT JOIN`, everything works fine.

I have seen the two string values I try to join on in the database, and they are the same in `table_4` and `table_3`. However I do not get any data.

Do I have to trim the strings or manipulate them in some way before the query results in a match?

Comment: The WHERE condition will convert your "LEFT JOIN" to an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Have you tried using `LEFT JOIN table_4 ON table_3...` instead of using `WHERE`

Comment: @NigelRen Do you mean like this `LEFT JOIN table_4 ON table_3.string_value=table_4.string_value'`

Comment: Your syntax now doesn't make sense - `LEFT JOIN table_4 ON table_3 WHERE table_3.string_value` should be `LEFT JOIN table_4 ON table_3.string_value ...`

Comment: I tend to use `...` when I don't want to type out a whole row of code.

Comment: You should get a syntax error with this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for your joins is wrong. A query can have only a single WHERE clause. You want to use an `ON` clause to specify your JOIN conditions.

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM table_1
      INNER JOIN on ON table_1.id=table_2.id
      INNER JOIN on ON table_1.integer_value=table_3.int_value
      LEFT JOIN table_4 ON table_3.string_value=table_4.string_value';
```